# status.sh bash script echo padding. How?

Tags: bash, shell

I've create a script called `status.sh` and I saved it to `/home/status.sh`.

This script gives the user general information about the Digital Ocean Droplet they are logged in to.

In the following output you can see that I have vertically aligned the text for the config and log outputs. The service status for each service is however not aligned.

How can I add padding to the echo output inside the function?

Take a look:

[image: sample_image_1]

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ANSI Color escape codes:

# Black        0;30     Dark Gray     1;30
# Red          0;31     Light Red     1;31
# Green        0;32     Light Green   1;32
# Brown/Orange 0;33     Yellow        1;33
# Blue         0;34     Light Blue    1;34
# Purple       0;35     Light Purple  1;35
# Cyan         0;36     Light Cyan    1;36
# Light Gray   0;37     White         1;37

BLACK='\033[0;30m'
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
ORANGE='\033[0;33m'
BLUE='\033[0;34m'
PURPLE='\033[0;35m'
CYAN='\033[0;36m'
LGRAY='\033[0;37m'

DGRAY='\033[1;30m'
LRED='\033[1;31m'
LGREEN='\033[1;32m'
YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
LBLUE='\033[1;34m'
LPURPLE='\033[1;35m'
LCYAN='\033[1;36m'
WHITE='\033[1;37m'

NC='\033[0m' # No Color

echo ""
echo -e "${LBLUE}Digital Ocean Droplet Info${NC}"
echo ""
echo "1 VCPU + 1GB RAM + 20GB SSD @ 5.00/mo"
echo ""

echo ""
echo -e "${ORANGE}Web Server Status:${NC}"
echo ""

# function to check service status
function serviceStatus()
{

  # Get service status for service name...
  systemctl is-active --quiet $1

  # Evaluate service status by response code returned from systemctl command...
  if [ $? != 0 ]
    then
      echo -e $1" : ${RED}inactive${NC}";
    else
      echo -e $1" : ${GREEN}active${NC}";
  fi;

}

# call function...
serviceStatus "firewalld"
# call function...
serviceStatus "php7.3-fpm"
# call function...
serviceStatus "nginx"

echo ""
echo -e "${ORANGE}Config files located at:${NC}"
echo ""
echo -e "${CYAN}firewalld${NC} config -> ${DGRAY}/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf${NC}"
echo -e "      ${CYAN}php${NC} config -> ${DGRAY}/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini${NC}"
echo -e "  ${CYAN}php-fpm${NC} config -> ${DGRAY}/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf${NC}"
echo -e "    ${CYAN}nginx${NC} config -> ${DGRAY}/etc/nginx/nginx.conf${NC}"
echo ""
echo -e "${ORANGE}Log files located at:${NC}"
echo ""
echo -e "${CYAN}firewalld${NC}    log -> ${DGRAY}/var/log/firewalld${NC}"
echo -e "  ${CYAN}php-fpm${NC}    log -> ${DGRAY}/var/log/php7.3-fpm.log${NC}"
echo -e "    ${CYAN}nginx${NC}    log -> ${DGRAY}/var/log/nginx/access.log${NC}"
echo -e "    ${CYAN}nginx${NC}    log -> ${DGRAY}/var/log/nginx/error.log${NC}"
echo ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `printf`:

```
printf "%-15s : %s\n" "firewalld" "active"
printf "%-15s : %s\n" "nginx" "active"
```

Output:

```
firewalld       : active
nginx           : active
```

---

See: `help printf`

Comment: Testing... Hoping that it works with color escape sequences allowed by making use of the `-e` option in the echo command.

Comment: To use colours switch from `%s` to `%b`.

Comment: Purrrrrrrrrrrrrfect.